# How can I include static content in my Community?

Tags: community, html, napili

I am using the Napili template for my community and would like to reference an image (stored in Static content) from my HTML Component.

Is there a way to do this without hardcoding the domain? As this will change between sandboxes/orgs.

**EDIT:**

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-frontend navbar-logged-in" id="main_header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="logo" href="/">
                    <img src="/resource/1516708830000/staticresourename" alt="" class="logo">
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-navbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="//www.site.com">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/secur/logout.jsp"> SIGN OUT </a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you uplaoded your image(s) to your asset library, you can achieve this. m,aybe you can share how and what you have tried?

Comment: I have added the HTML Editor block I have inserted into the header of my Napili template.

Comment: so, you would like to reuse the image you uploaded through the branding panel, the header image or company logo?

Comment: Whichever is easier (either through brand editor, static library or the asset library), I just need a way to add in within my code so I can alter it using CSS later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual way to do this would be to store the images and any other files like CSS files in the Asset Library, the library would provide relative URLs which you can use in your HTML blocks.

Answer (score 1):

From the Lightning Component Developer Guide, you should probably check:

[Tokens Bundles](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/tokens_bundles.htm)

When you define your token attributres, you can set a headerImageUrl and reference it in the Style of your lightning component.

This way, the image you reference through the branding editor (header image) will be referenced "dynamically" in your component.

You can also set a relative path reference in your component's style for whatever image you want to reference from the Assset Library.